# How to add a button permanently in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is there a way in python tkinter to, when you add a button to a page, to do it permanently even when you stop and run the program again?
Like if u were to add the button to a database.
I don't know if there's a way to put the widget in a sql table...

Comment: You can't put a widget in a SQL database, but you can put the data necessary to recreate the widget in a database. Have you tried that? Create a row for each "permanent" button, and then when the app starts up you read the rows and create the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm not completely understanding what you mean by that... could you please write an exemple so i can understand? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store tkinter objects in a database. The solution is to add information to a file or database that allows you to recreate the buttons when you start the application. For example, you can save the button label to a row in the database, and at startup read the rows and create a button for each row.

Here's a complete program that illustrates the process. Notice that each time you create a button the text is retrieved from the entry widget and it is added to the database. At startup the code will query the database and recreate the buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

def init_db():
    global db
    db = sqlite3.connect("buttons.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS buttons (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, label VARCHAR)")

def add_button():
    button_text = entry.get() or "Button"
    entry.delete(0, "end")

    create_button(button_text)
    save_button(button_text)

def save_button(button_text):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(label) VALUES(?)", (button_text,))
    db.commit()

def create_button(button_text):
    button = tk.Button(root, text=button_text)
    button.pack(side="top")

def restore_buttons():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT id, label from buttons")
    for (row_id, button_text) in cursor.fetchall():
        create_button(button_text)

root = tk.Tk()
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
toolbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

button = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Add Button", command=add_button)
entry = tk.Entry(toolbar)

entry.pack(side="left")
button.pack(side="left")

init_db()
restore_buttons()

root.mainloop()
```